# WSS 3 on SBS 2003

Tags: upgrade, wss, small-business-server

I just recently identified that upgrading WSS 2 to WSS 3 on SBS 2003 is not supported. I need to plan the best approach to get a client using WSS 3 with the current SBS 2003 environment.  It is a stand alone server where WSS 2 is installed.  The company is using the site as the current intranet portal.  My question is how to be able to preserve this portal in the WSS 3 instance that I install.  Will it be as simple as exporting and importing the sites from WSS 2 to the new WSS 3 site?  Should I consider a migration tool?  The end result would be to shut down WSS 2 on the server and have the WSS 3 instance become the new portal.

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SBS 2003 you will have to do a side by side install.  You can use WSS3 to support team sites, but you still need WSS2 to keep all the integrated functions from the built in company web.

You can remove WSS2 and only have WSS3 but you none of the built in integration points will work.

Technet article

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc671966(WS.10).aspx

Guide to installing WSS3.0 on SBS 2003

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13024

Moving / Copying MSDTE DB's
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925190/en-us

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jesus. I am not familar with SBS 2003 so if you could give me an idea on the built in integration points that will fail that would be appreciated.

Comment: I've added a few more links, one with more information on what breaks (it's been a long time since I've worked with SBS 2003) and the other on moving MSDTE databases.

Comment: Let me add, that if you upgrade the WSS2.0 SBS 2003 will not longer be in a Microsoft supported state.

Comment: Jesus, If I were to do a side by side, what would you recommend for migrating data from WSS 2 to WSS 3?  It seems like the document you attached is for moving to another server.  I am staying within the current MSDTE DB as this is a simple stand alone environment.

Comment: You still have to get the content out of 2 and into 3.  You can't use the same DB.  You could attempt to backup and restore to a new DB on the same instance, than attach that to WSS3 (database attach upgrade).  I must admit that I have not tried this route.  If that fails you, then you will need to look at migration methods and tools.